# TextView not getting updated immediately

Tags: android, textview

I have a text view(caption) placed over my image view. When I change the text its visible on the screen but when I save that image nothing appears on the image when I check it out in my gallery.

When I use runOnUiThread it works only when I change the colour of text along with changing the text.

However it works fine if I use custom view and draw the text on the canvas, the changes are immediately saved on the image.

Why is this? What actually is happening in background? and how can I get the text view changes get updated immediately?

Below is my code to update text view
(I am cropping my relative layout with image view's width and height by calling the crop() function)

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
        public void run() {
            textView.setText(textPreview.getText().toString());
            if(colorSet == 1){
                textView.setTextColor(col);
             }
        });

    crop();

   dialog.dismiss();

}
```

My crop() function - newBitmap is my image view where caption is being placed

```
    newBitmap1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(relLay.getDrawingCache(),0,0,newBitmap.getWidth(),newBitmap.getHeight());
    SharingFile = CreateTempFile(newBitmap1);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + SharingFile)) ;
    setIntent(shareIntent);
```

Comment: TextView is just a view that is overlaid on top of your displayed image without actually changing the bitmap. If you want to change an image, you will have to draw on top of that and save it. However, you can always overlay a textview on top of an image and take a screenshot.

Comment: In this case I am actually cropping my relative layout with my image view width and height.

Comment: Include the part of the code where you are making changes to the image along with the part where you are saving it.

Comment: I have added my crop function in the question

Comment: I am actually sharing my image

Comment: The cropping needs to be done after the text update. Try including the call to crop() inside run() - after the text update.

Comment: How ever I have solved it using runnable with help of below link's 5.3. Example - http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html

Comment: Thanks for your time and help ur last comment lead me to my solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the call to crop() to happen **after** the text update on UI thread - not in parallel. So, try including the call to crop in the run() method after the text update.

Comment: I will give u the credit since you made me think in the correct way :)

Comment: for users who are seeking for a more precise ans refer below link's 5.3. Example - http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html